# Communicate an iOS device with a non iOS device via WIFI

Tags: ios, wifi

I am working on a project in which I should connect an iPhone to an accessory via WIFI.
Some blogs spoke about `ExternalAccessory.framework` but this one is used for establishing connection via Bluetooth.
What library should I use to achieve this ? Could any one please point me to the right direction ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Assuming that you don't know the ip address of the device you want to connect to)*

From an iOS standpoint you want to use [`NSNetService`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002736) to discover devices on the network which you can connect to.

This requires that your other device can use `mdnsresponder` to publish its details onto the network such that it can be found and connected to.

If you do know the ip address (or, once you do know it) then you can use `NSURLConnection` / `NSStream` to connect to the device (depending on what capabilities it offers).